# Titanium Appcelerator - can't create new project & iOS simulator not running kitchen sink

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a fresh installation of Titanium Appcelerator on Mac OS (Mountain Lion - 10.8.2); I did all the updates to Titanium Studio + SDK + GIT and it confirms the iOS framework (Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 6) is installed correctly but I'm encountering two issues:

- when running kitchen sink on iPad / iPhone iOS device simulator I get an "Launching (iPad/iPhone) Simulator - 'Kitchen Sink' has encountered a problem" message
- when I try to create a brand new project I get an "unable to create project" message

The error details in both cases start with:

> Launching simulator process failed
>   [ERROR] :  Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 
>   '/Users/(user_name)/.titanium/auth_session.json'

I've already tried clearing / deleting the build folder for the first error but nothing changes.

The .titanium folder under my user folder doesn't exist at all. I've already uninstalled and re-installed a couple of times. Again, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by installing titanium manually.

```
    # Mac & Linux
    sudo npm install -g titanium

    # Windows
    npm install -g titanium
```